# Cassandra destination is not a direct buffer

Tags: cassandra, snappy, high-load

our cassandra nodes reach nearly 90% load without any requests. In the log we can see this exception. Has anybody at least an idea?

Our software runs without problems in other environments.

> INFO 
>   [CompactionExecutor:36366] 2017-02-02 12:27:06,708
>   NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (512.000MiB),
>   cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB
>
> DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-31] 2017-02-02 15:15:43,015
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Failed; received 0 of 1 responses WARN 
>   [SharedPool-Worker-34] 2017-02-02 15:15:43,015
>   AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on
>   thread Thread[SharedPool-Worker-34,5,main]: {}
>   org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [NOT_A_DIRECT_BUFFER] destination is
>   not a direct buffer   at
>   org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:509)
>   ~[snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor.uncompress(SnappyCompressor.java:102)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedSegmentedFile$Mmap.readChunk(CompressedSegmentedFile.java:323)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.load(ChunkCache.java:137)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache.load(ChunkCache.java:19)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:2949)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$15(BoundedLocalCache.java:1807)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:1805)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:1788)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:97)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:66)
>   ~[caffeine-2.2.6.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache$CachingRebufferer.rebuffer(ChunkCache.java:215)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.cache.ChunkCache$CachingRebufferer.rebuffer(ChunkCache.java:193)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.reBufferAt(RandomAccessReader.java:78)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.seek(RandomAccessReader.java:220)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.seekToCurrentRangeStart(BigTableScanner.java:186)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.access$200(BigTableScanner.java:51)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(BigTableScanner.java:285)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner$KeyScanningIterator.computeNext(BigTableScanner.java:265)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableScanner.hasNext(BigTableScanner.java:245)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:374)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.advance(MergeIterator.java:186)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:155)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$4.hasNext(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:216)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BasePartitions.hasNext(BasePartitions.java:72)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:289)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:134)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.(ReadResponse.java:127)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.(ReadResponse.java:123)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:65)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:292)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1799)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2466)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_112]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]    at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
>   DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-30] 2017-02-02 15:15:43,819
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [SharedPool-Worker-30] 2017-02-02 15:15:52,744
>   ReadCallback.java:126 - Timed out; received 1 of 2 responses
>   (including data) DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2017-02-02 15:15:58,789
>   FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2154429836 for
>   /172.26.216.8 DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2017-02-02 15:15:58,789
>   FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2000371819 for
>   /172.26.216.4 DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2017-02-02 15:16:00,999
>   FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2209666046 for
>   /172.26.216.8 DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2017-02-02 15:16:00,999
>   FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2209670711 for
>   /172.26.216.4

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/Ovz89qTIIDI please share the keyspace and table create statements. Looks like you have misconfigured compression for version of cassandra you are using.

Comment: CREATE KEYSPACE monitor WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.100000 AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  compaction={'sstable_size_in_mb': '160', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

Comment: As i said, the same keyspace and table structure is working on other infrastructure

Comment: I understand, but are the cassandra versions the same? if it's something urgent, simply remove the compression part if you don't need it (I think this is staging or something). It also looks that this depends on cassandra version you are using.

Comment: Thanks, i will check this... really crazy

Comment: also check cassandra.yaml file for property memtable_allocation_type

Comment: After restarting the cluster the problem no longer occurred.untrustworthy...